# Trying to get Raspbian LITE to open Start X automatically to boot a Web Browser

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, .bash-profile, openbox

So I am very new to linux and Raspberry Pi's. I am trying to get my pi to boot up into a web browser. I have been following these instructions (https://die-antwort.eu/techblog/2017-12-setup-raspberry-pi-for-kiosk-mode/).

However, I am stuck on the very last part appending this line 
[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && startx -- -nocursor
to the .bash_profile. 
I can not find the .bash_profile nor do I know where to append that line. Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In linux, files prepended with a dot are hidden; using the command `ls -a` or Ctrl-h in a graphical file browser will show all files. .bash_profile should be in /home/pi in Raspbian.